# Data goes to warm store and cold store simultaneously in Azure time Series Insight

Tags: azure, azure-timeseries-insights

I want to use Azure Time Series insight. I want to know data goes to warm and cold store simultaneously or when warm store rentention expires then it goes to cold store( i.e. Azure Storage).

Please confirm.

Regards,
Amit Agrawal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data goes to both stores simultaneously as it's ingested. Data in warm is stored for the duration of the retention period and then dropped. Data in cold store is stored indefinitely. You can read more about storage [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/time-series-insights/concepts-storage#provisioning).